# White margin added at top when trying to move div

Tags: html, css

I have been working on a website the last couple of days, and today I just ran into a problem when I wanted to move the navigation bar down from the top of the page. This have never been a problem for me, but I have read my code so many times by now, that I'm not able to find the mistake.

What I did was to add a *margin-top: 50px;* to my navigation div, but it then proceeds to create a white border above the parent div.

CSS

```
#section1 {
background-image: url("images/section1bg.jpg");
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
}

#topnav {
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: right;
width: 400px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
border-bottom: 1px solid white;
position: relative;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="section1">
<div id="topnav">
    <a href="#" class="topnav">Languages</a>
    <a href="/contact/"  class="topnav">Contact</a>
</div>
    ... other content
</div>
```

The image below should show the issue.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e1mW.png

If anyone has an idea about what to do, I would love to hear from you.
Thank you :)

Comment: Try using padding instead of margin...may be that will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `margin-top: 50px;` to `padding-top: 50px;`

```
#topnav {
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: right;
  width: 400px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Now define your** `#section1` `id` **css** `overflow:hidden;`

```
#section1 {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/85a3b23b/)**

Answer (score 0):

What color do you want the 'white' space you could create a div on top

```
<div style="background-color:#black;width:100%;height:50px"><div>
```